# iOS - Autoshrink size enforced across multiple labels

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, uilabel

Often I get asked to implement a beautifully designed column type layout (say with 3 columns) by our UX team which has been created the design based on an iPhone 6 layout. I then test the built design on an iPhone 5 and see that the text collides or is truncated.

I would like to use the autoshrink capability of interface builder to handle this situation on the smaller screen but it is not desirable for only one of the labels to be shrunk. I would like for the behaviour to be that if one label is shrunk, they all are shrunk - sort of like an "equal font size" layout constraint.

Does anyone have a solution programmatic or through Interface builder which can impose such a constraint to ensure that if space is insufficient and an autoshrink is triggered on one label the other labels will also be shrunk to the same size?

Thank you

Comment: "I would like to use the autoshrink capability of interface builder " What are you talking about? Does "shrink" mean shrink the width of the label or shrink the size of the font?

Comment: By shrink I mean size of the font. In Interface Builder all labels have a property for "autoshrink" which by default is set to "fixed font size". You can also specify a minimum font size/scale. However, this only is applied to 1 label. I would like to know if it's possible to create a dependency such that if 1 label shrinks multiple will shrink. So instead of shrinking 1 label to size 12 font and the 2 others at size 18 it would shrink all 3 to size 15, etc the largest amount that would fit.